# Express Passport.js: req.user VERSUS req.session.passport.user

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

As per this article

http://toon.io/understanding-passportjs-authentication-flow/

it looks as though PassportJS/Express store the logged in user in two places

```
req.user
```

and

```
req.session.passport.user
```

why both? which one should I use?  When I logout with passport, does it destroy both req.user and req.session.passport.user?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should always, *always* use `req.user` in your own code -- this is important because if you use `req.session.passport.user`, you're essentially pulling user information out of a session cookie (which may be outdated).

It's always best to rely on `req.user` as opposed to cookie data directly, as depending on your implementation, that information might be out of date.

And to answer your question: if you log a user out, both `req.session` and `req.user` will no longer be available.

Comment: Wouldn't `req.session.passport.user` actually be pulling information from the session itself (not the session cookie)?  I could be somehow mistaken, but unless you have sessions disabled isn't `req.user` really just mapped to `req.session.passport.user`?  I can't see how the two would actually ever be different.  Now if you were to somehow store actual data in the cookie (versus just the session id) and then access that data via `req.cookies` then it certainly could be out of date, but that's a completely different scenario.

Comment: No -- `req.session.passport.user` is pulled from the session cookie (nowhere else). This is how it works with the cookie based session auth unless you're using some other form.

Comment: Maybe we're talking about different things, but that doesn't make sense in the context of using a MemoryStore or server-based session storage.  When using a server-side session store, the session cookie (sent to the browser) only stores the session ID.  All data remains on the server.  The whole point of a session is to keep data available and up to date on the server for a given user.  The session cookie only allows a browser to stay linked to a particular session.  Accessing data through `req.session` will always contain the latest session information.

Comment: What you're saying may be true if the session is using a cookieSession store (where the entire session is maintained in the cookie), but that's not what I think most people are talking about when using the term "session cookie".  The most common scenario would be to have a server-side session store with an ID stored in a cookie sent to the browser.

Comment: This is correct. My point here in recommending the other usage is that it does NOT depend on what session store is being used, so in general is safer. There are definitely circumstances (which you've pointed out) where this is not the case.