# Passport session not updating

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm trying to update the passport session after user info change using:

```
user.save(function(err) {
if (err) return next(err)
// What's happening in passport's session? Check a specific field...
console.log("Before relogin: "+req.session.passport.user.changedField)

req.login(user, function(err) {
    if (err) return next(err)

    console.log("After relogin: "+req.session.passport.user.changedField)
    res.send(200)
})
})
```

But even after re-login, with no errors my passport session remains the same. I have to manually logout and log back in for the session info to update. Can anyone explain what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

Passport sets `req.user` using the function you have provided with `passport.deserializeUser`. You are using `req.session.passport.user` [which is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055744/express-passport-js-req-user-versus-req-session-passport-user%20which%20is%20incorrect). There is no need to re-login after change of user information - `deserializeUser` is called on every request, and this is where you fetch the user information from your database. Then you access it via `req.user`.

Comment: Better to update the user in session only when it actually changes, so you don't have to hit the database per every request and slowdown all your website. I mean, how often a user object changes? A bit, right? So..