# Get current user to multiple passport.js strategies

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, passport.js

I'm trying to use multiple passport.js strategies in my node app with mysql.
But I'm falling in Update the same user in the database for different strategies.
This is my code so far:

```
passport.use('slack', new SlackStrategy({
        clientID: process.env.SLACK_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.SLACK_SECRET,
        callbackURL: process.env.SLACK_REDIRECT,
        scope: "incoming-webhook users:read"
    },
        function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

            console.log('req');
            JSON.stringify(req);
            console.log('end req');

            var values = { 
                where: { slack_id: profile.id }, 
                defaults: {slack_id: profile.id, name: profile.displayName} 
            };

            User.findOrCreate(values)
            .then(function(err, user) {
                return done();
            });
        }
    ));
```

I tried to check for req to get the current user logged in and then update it.
But nothing is being stored on this.

How can I do this?

Comment: req.session.passport.user?

Comment: @xShirase req.session.passport.user it's undefined. How can I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055744/express-passport-js-req-user-versus-req-session-passport-user