# passport js session user is always the same user

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am using express sessions to manage my users via google and Facebook login, I have setup a login where the user is logged out after clicking or after going to /logout URL but all of the sudden if i log in with two different google accounts i still see that old user maintained in `req.user` and all users are loaded with the details of the same `req.user`, what might have done wrong here?

Here is my config

```
 var store = new MongoDBStore({
    uri: dbUrl,
    collection: "sessions",
  });
  app.use(
    session({
      secret: "keyboard cat",
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      store: store,
    })
  );
  app.use(methodOverride());
  app.use(cookieParser("some-secret-value-here"));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(passport.authenticate("session"));
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.session = req.user;
    next();
  });
```

Here are my auth routes

```
router.get("/logout", function (req, res, next) {
    req.logout(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.redirect("/");
    });
  });
  //google authentication
  router.get(
    "/auth/google",
    passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["email", "profile"] })
  );

  router.get(
    "/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
      successRedirect: "/dashboard",
      failureRedirect: "/login",
    })
  );
  //facebook authentication
  router.get(
    "/login/facebook",
    passport.authenticate("facebook", {
      scope: ["email", "public_profile"],
    })
  );
  router.get(
    "/oauth2/redirect/facebook",
    passport.authenticate("facebook", {
      failureRedirect: "/login",
      failureMessage: true,
    }),
    function (req, res) {
      res.redirect("/dashboard");
    }
  );
```

Here is my passport serialize and deserialize user

```
 passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem too and I have solved it. I was using `req.sessionStore.sessions` but the only right solution is to use `req.user` nothing else. For more info see [Express Passport.js: req.user VERSUS req.session.passport.user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055744/express-passport-js-req-user-versus-req-session-passport-user)